# AngularJS 'ng-switch-when' with an expression

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-switch

I know `ng-switch-when` expects a value, but I created a `ng-repeat` with it.

What do I need to make for this to work?:

```
<div ng-switch-when="2" ng-controller="pages as page" ng-switch="page.get()">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
        <div ng-switch-when="{{ i }}">
            {{i}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-hide="page.is(1)" ng-click="page.prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous Page</button>
    <button ng-hide="page.is(5)" ng-click="page.next()" class="btn btn-info">Next Page</button>
    <br>
    <label>Page {{page.get()}}</label>
</div>
```

I want to show the `div` when the value is "i", but angularjs doesn't accept that.

> I don't know if that makes much difference, but I'm using a `ng-switch` inside a `div` which is being displayed by another `ng-switch`.

Thanks in advance

> EDIT 1:
>   I want to create with a `ng-repeat` 5 pages, which are inside a ng-switch.
>   When the repeat "i" value is one, I want the page it created to be displayed when the switch value equals one, also, and that for the rest of them

Comment: Can You explain a little more what output do you expect ?

Comment: I want to create with a `ng-repeat` 5 pages, which are inside a ng-switch.
When the repeat "i" value is one, I want the page it created to be displayed when the switch value equals one, also, and that for the rest of them

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="pages as page" ng-switch="page.get()">
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
      <div ng-switch = "i">
        <div ng-switch-when = "1">
          1
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "2">
          2
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "3">
          3
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "4">
          4
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when = "5">
          5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button ng-hide="page.is(1)" ng-click="page.prev()" class="btn btn-info">Previous Page</button>
    <button ng-hide="page.is(5)" ng-click="page.next()" class="btn btn-info">Next Page</button>
    <br>
    <label>Page {{page.get()}}</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually want to avoid creating the five `div`s, that's why I want to make like above
I just don't know if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

You can't.

From [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch):

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against.

What you could do to achieve the same result is use `ng-show` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
    <div ng-show="page.get() === i">
        {{i}}
    </div>
</div>
```